# how to stream 3gp video files in c++

Tags: c++, streaming, 3gp

i like to be able to stream and display 3gp video files 
that in my case coming from the YouTube Api 
im programing in c++. 
can it be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Which OSes are you doing this for? On Windows, typically you use either DirectShow or Media Foundation for media playback. Provided that you can get the 3gp stream from YouTube, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: im doing it in windows xp , i even can't find any thing in the web that explain me how to do this

Comment: Wait, are you trying to broadcast the stream or are you trying to play the stream? These two are very different things. If you want to play the stream in something like a media player, then DirectShow documentation and samples should get you where you want to go. If you want to broadcast it... I don't really know what you need to do.